# Woocommerce and Yoast product search error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

I've been trying to use product search in the admin area, it used to work fine, now i get this errors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM mu05iq_posts posts
             LEFT JOIN mu05iq_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id
              LEFT JOIN mu05iq_wc_product_meta_lookup parent_wc_product_meta_lookup
             ON posts.post_type = 'product_variation' AND parent_wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id = posts.post_parent 
            WHERE posts.post_type IN ('product','product_variation')
             AND (  ( ( posts.post_title LIKE '%fiber%') OR ( posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%fiber%') OR ( posts.post_content LIKE '%fiber%' ) OR ( wc_product_meta_lookup.sku LIKE '%fiber%' )  OR ( wc_product_meta_lookup.sku = "" AND parent_wc_product_meta_lookup.sku LIKE '%fiber%' ) )) 
            
            
            ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC
        

WordPress database error: [Unknown column '1' in 'where clause']
SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM mu05iq_postmeta WHERE post_id IN( SELECT ID FROM mu05iq_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' ) && meta_value = "1" AND meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_is_cornerstone'
```

If anyone has any ideas i would appreciate it.
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is experiencing this issue, it's a digital ocean managed database setting, when you create a database cluster it sets up some settings in Global SQL Mode, just remove ANSI_QUOTES. That fixed my issue.